# Adobe Air 4.0 Mobile As3 - StageText restrict

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mobile, air

we added a StageText object to our stage.
Everything works fine until we add the restriction:

```
myTextFieldName = new StageText();
myTextFieldName.editable = true;
myTextFieldName.autoCorrect = false;
myTextFieldName.stage = this.stage;
myTextFieldName.maxChars = 15;
myTextFieldName.fontSize = 35*SWF_HALF_WIDTH*2/620;
myTextFieldName.viewPort = new Rectangle(SWF_HALF_WIDTH-_nameIpSprite.width/2+255*SWF_HALF_WIDTH*2/620, _nameIpSprite.y+21*SWF_HALF_WIDTH*2/620,222*SWF_HALF_WIDTH*2/620,40*SWF_HALF_WIDTH*2/620); 
myTextFieldName.text = "";
myTextFieldName.restrict = "0-9a-zA-Z";
myTextFieldName.returnKeyLabel = ReturnKeyLabel.GO;
```

The text gets restricted as we defined it but the big problem is that it inserts the characters that have already been typed in if you enter a new letter.

So I type in a "f" and after that an "m". It automatically adds an additional f so the result is "ffm" instead of "fm".

We also tried to add a change eventlistener:

```
myTextFieldName.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, textFieldChangeEventHandler);

private function textFieldChangeEventHandler(event:Event):void
{
    trace(event.target.text);
    //Manage text
}
```

If we use that the cursor always went to the beginning of the string and every new letter is added at the beginning instead of the end...

Any experience with that?

Best

Answer (score 0):

From what you saying i think it is a bug, i also found a bug in stage text related to RTL text and report it [here](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3693360),
i suggest to report this bug and use a code to restrict user input as workaround.